# Rendering requests with Django

Tags: python, django

I have written a method in my views.py in such a way that I'm showing a form for a GET request (formExample1.html), and after submiting the form with a POST and doing some stuff, I'm showing a results page (results.html).

The form is correctly displayed, and when the form is submitted, a POST request is correctly generated and received by the Django server, so it does all the stuff it is supposed to do, but finally it is not rendering the results page: the browser stays at the form page.

```
 def formExample1(request):
    print 'RECEIVED REQUEST: ' + request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        value1 = request.REQUEST['value1']
        value2 = int(request.REQUEST['value2'])
        # etc
        #
        geojson = createGeoJSON(value1, value2)
        print geojson #json is correctly generated at printed at server console
        return render(request, 'results.html', {'geo_json': geojson}) # This is what is not working
    else: #GET
        return render(request, 'formExample1.html') # Working OK
```

Also, if I don't pass the geoJSON object to the render function, it is not working either.

I guess I'm missing some detail here. Any help?

EDIT: I don't think showing the results page will help, but here it is. It's a simple html right now, including an OpenLayers map and intending to feed data to the map from the geojson (what I still don't know how to do it since I don't know how to get the geojson i'm passing, but that's a different story). So:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lon = 5;
        var lat = 40;
        var zoom = 5;
        var map, layer;

        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", 
                    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                    {layers: 'basic'} );
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);

            // Here is where I'm trying to get the geojson I'm passing, but I think this is wrong. Anyway has nothing to do with current problem
            var featurecollection = {{ geo_json|safe }};
            var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
            var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(); 
            map.addLayer(vector_layer);
            vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(featurecollection));

        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <h1 id="title">GeoJSON Example</h1>

    <div id="tags">
       JSON, GeoJSON
    </div>

      <p id="shortdesc">
        Demonstrate the use of the GeoJSON format.
    </p>
    <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
    <div id="docs">
        <p>This example uses the GeoJSON format.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is 99% the same HTML posted as an [example of OpenLayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/geojson.html). So I guess it's ok. Problem must be somewhere else.

EDIT2: Also adding formExample1.html code:

```
<html>
<head>  
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">

    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle { z-index: 1; }
    </style>

    <script>
$(function() {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    // DatePicker function:
    $(function() {
        var today = new Date()
        $( "#id_startDate" ).datepicker({
            minDate: 0
        });
    });

    // Interval slider function:

    $(function() {
        var currentHour = new Date().getUTCHours()
        $( "#id_interval" ).slider({
          range: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 72,
          values: [ currentHour, currentHour+48 ], // By default from current hour 1st day to same hour last day
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var startDay = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 24) + 1
            var startHour = ui.values[0] % 24
            var endDay = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 24) + 1
            var endHour = ui.values[1] % 24

            $( "#amount" ).val( "From " + startHour + ":00h day " + startDay +
             " to " + endHour + ":00h day " + endDay + " (UTC)");
          }
        });

        $( "#amount" ).val( "From " + currentHour + ":00h day 1 to " + currentHour + ":00h day 3 (UTC)");
    });

    // Threshold spinner selector:
    $(function() {
    var id_threshold = $( "#id_threshold" ).spinner();
        id_threshold.spinner( "value", 15 );
        id_threshold.spinner( "option", "min", 0 );
        $( "button" ).button();
    });

    // Movie player slider:
    $(function() {
        $( "#player-slider" ).slider({
          range: "min",
          value: 0,
          min: 0,
          max: 1000,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            //$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
          }
        });
        // Modify this line to show somehow the current displayed prediction hour
        //$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#player-slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    });

    // Play button
    $( "#id_playButton" ).click(function() {
        var postdata = {
            'startdate': $("#id_startDate").datepicker("getDate"),
            'starthour': $("#id_interval").slider("values", 0),
            'endhour': $("#id_interval").slider("values", 1),
            'threshold': $("#id_threshold").val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
        };
        $.post('', postdata);

    });
});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="id_startDate"></p>
        <p>
            <label for="amount">Interval:</label>
            <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
        </p>
        <p> <div id="id_interval"></div> </p>

        <p>
          <label for="id_threshold">Threshold:</label>
          <input id="id_threshold" name="value" />
        </p>

        <p> <div id="player-slider"></div> </p>

        <p>
        <p>
          <button id="id_playButton">Play</button>
        </p>
        </p>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the browser stays at the form page"? You're not redirecting here, so you will still see the form URL, but you will get the content from results.html. Is that not what you see?

Comment: is it possible that something is wrong with templates?

Comment: Can you show us results.html? BTW, your url will not change.

Comment: I am not hopping to see the URL changing: this is being used at localhost:8000/form/. I expect it to remain there, but showing results.html and not formExample1.html. BTW, there is nothing wrong with results.html, since I have tested it in a different URL before and is rendered perfectly

Comment: Did you turn on `DEBUG`?

Comment: Yes, DEBUG is True, and I have also installed the Django-debug-bar

Comment: *Please* can you tell us what you are actually seeing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see the form page, all the time, no matter what. And I can see at Django console: RECEIVED REQUEST: POST, it prints the geojson and also says "POST /form/ HTTP/1.1" 200 314081. Note that /form/ is the URL where I'm redirecting this view, intended to show the form when the request is a GET, and teh results when it is a POST. Maybe there are smarter ways of doing what I intend to do, but I don't know of any

Comment: Then you'll need to show your templates, because the code you've shown above would do exactly what you want, ie show the contents of results.html. Perhaps the template itself is including the form for some reason.

Comment: I am curious as to what's in `formExample1.html`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid consider your curiosity satisfied :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you submit the form. Since you are using ajax - the resulting HTML is being sent back to your ajax call, where its not rendered and simply discarded.

To fix this:

1. Use a standard form (don't forget `{% csrf_token %}`. You can then render the template as you are doing now - or - redirect to the view as is best practice for `POST` requests.
2. If you want to use ajax, capture the result with a callback, and render the response. If you want to do this, simply return the JSON without a template. Update your form HTML with the javascript in your `results.html`.

Comment: Just returning a redirect wouldn't help, because all that would happen would be the ajax POST getting a 302 which it would ignore just as it is ignoring the current 200. OP needs to either get rid of the Ajax completely, or do actually something with the returned data.

Comment: Oops, you are right Daniel. I don't know why ajax is being used by the OP in the first place :/

Comment: Standard Django forms don't look as nice as JQuery-UI ones. That's why I'm using AJAX. Could you give further explanations about the second option?

Comment: Honestly, that's not a valid reason. You can use whatever styling you want in your forms, or use something like [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Over complicating the issue with ajax is not the answer.

Comment: There is a lack of documentation about how to style Django forms or even how to use crispy-forms. If it were properly documentated, I would have taken that road. I don't see why it is so difficult to use junit-ui forms with django anyway